# Options market makers market share

Tags: options

Sorry if the question is confusing but I am curious what percentage of options is written by market makers. I know the vast majority of retail investors don't write options; they buy options. I imagine only a few big investors like Warren Buffet write options. Perhaps some hedge funds do. Still is it 90% or 99% of (stock) options that are written by market makers?

Part of my interest is because market makers keep pretty wide bid/wide spreads for many stock options so the only chance to see a better spread is when someone else is selling the option. Doesn't seem to happen much.

Comment: Don't rely on bid/ask spreads you see in options quotes, especially in the US. They are just indicative, you will get hit way inside if you post a quote within the bid/ask.

Comment: This probably depends on the market as well. Which one are you interested in?